# How to get JsHint version from a custom reporter

Tags: scope, customization, reporting, jshint

Each custom reporter in JsHint receives 3 arguments : `results, data, and options`.

I'd like to be able to display the current JsHint version in the output generated by the reporter but it doesn't seem to be provided by any of the variables described above.

Am I missing something obvious, or is there another way to grab it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a function property to store the version:

```
reporter.version = "1.2.3";
```

then add a reference to it in the reporter source:

```
console.log(reporter.version ? "JSHint version: " + reporter.version + "\n" : "" + str + "\n" + len + ' error' + ((len === 1) ? '' : 's'));
```

**References**

- [JSHint Default Reporter source](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/src/reporters/default.js)